# How to display all background process IDs in executable file generated by a C++ program in unix?

Tags: c++

I need to write C++ program in unix system that allows user to run multiple processes (up to three at the same time) at the background. When three processes are currently running, further execution request will be pended (the process state is changed to “stopped”) and wait until another process is stopped or terminated. While processes are running at the background, the user can input commands to display information of the background processes, stop or kill a background process.

One of the commands is "bglist", whose function is to display the pid(s) of ALL background processes. For example, if I enter "bglist", it should show like this: 
bglist 
16529: demo1(running)
16605: demo2(stopped)
16613: demo3(terminated)

I have no idea how to check the status of ALL background processes while a program is running. Could anyone help me with the problem?

Comment: If you're running at most three background processes, why not just keep track of which of those are active?  Three pids doesn't seem liket much overhead.

Comment: While many "Unix" systems are standardized and share common API's, some parts are still platform and OS dependent. Including things like getting a list of running processes (foreground *and* background). So please specify the exact operating system you're targeting.